# Left join not giving all record Whats wrong with my query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

When I do a left outer join, I expect to get all the records that the query would return all record form the left table which not matched with the right table.

I want to select the record even the month data is not available in table. Suppose I have one record for five month. So when I will execute the my query i want total 12 record [left outer join] with 0 values form right table[client_service] table.

my Query is

```
SELECT  YEAR(CLIENT_SERVICE.cliserv_effective_date) As Year
        , MonthsTable.MonthName As Month
        , COUNT(CLIENT_SERVICE.cliserv_id) As ClientsInService 
FROM    MonthsTable
        left outer join CLIENT_SERVICE
         ON MonthsTable.MonthName = DATENAME(month,CLIENT_SERVICE.cliserv_effective_date)
WHERE   CLIENT_SERVICE.serv_id = 24
        AND CLIENT_SERVICE.cliserv_status = 'Active' 
        AND YEAR(CLIENT_SERVICE.cliserv_effective_date) BETWEEN 2014  AND 2015 
GROUP BY YEAR(CLIENT_SERVICE.cliserv_effective_date)
        , DATENAME(month,CLIENT_SERVICE.cliserv_effective_date)
        , [MonthsTable].MonthName
        , MONTH(CLIENT_SERVICE.cliserv_effective_date)  
ORDER BY YEAR(CLIENT_SERVICE.cliserv_effective_date)
        , MONTH(CLIENT_SERVICE.cliserv_effective_date);
```

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: It's the `CLIENT_SERVICE.serv_id = 24 CLIENT_SERVICE.cliserv_status = 'Active'` that eliminates the rows, because if there's no matching CLIENT_SERVICE row, those attributes will be NULL. Better to add those conditions in the "ON" part of the Join clause

Answer (score 0):

You have column of the right table in the where clause. put it in the on clause:

```
SELECT YEAR(CLIENT_SERVICE.cliserv_effective_date) As Year,
MonthsTable.MonthName As Month, COUNT(CLIENT_SERVICE.cliserv_id) As ClientsInService 
FROM MonthsTable left outer join  CLIENT_SERVICE ON MonthsTable.MonthName = DATENAME(month,CLIENT_SERVICE.cliserv_effective_date) and CLIENT_SERVICE.serv_id = 24 
 AND CLIENT_SERVICE.cliserv_status = 'Active' 
AND YEAR(CLIENT_SERVICE.cliserv_effective_date) BETWEEN 2014  AND 2015 
GROUP BY YEAR(CLIENT_SERVICE.cliserv_effective_date), DATENAME(month,CLIENT_SERVICE.cliserv_effective_date), 
[MonthsTable].MonthName,MONTH(CLIENT_SERVICE.cliserv_effective_date)  
ORDER BY YEAR(CLIENT_SERVICE.cliserv_effective_date), 
MONTH(CLIENT_SERVICE.cliserv_effective_date)
```